# JavaFX updating ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx

I'm getting tons of Unknown Source errors when updating content in my ComboBox.

Here is how I assign data to the combobox

```
DateBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(dateList));
DateBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

Then I add changelistener with this line

```
DateBox.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> listListener(newVal));
```

Now when I update the dateList and call the first segment of code again it works if I don't have that listener set. But if I call it with the listener set it spews out Unknown Source. Most likely I could bypass this by removing the listener before I update and then adding it back in but I couldn't find any way to do it. Also that wouldn't most likely be the correct way to do it.

How could I update the ComboBox (DateBox) without it causing all of those errors to popup. I assume the problem is that I change the content with setItems. I'd guess there is a way to cause the combobox to update but I couldn't find it.

Comment: What is `listListener` ?

Comment: Just a  simple subroutine that gets called. Here is the code 

    `private void listListener(Ajokerta newVal) {
        DateID=newVal.getKertaID();
        updateContent();
    }`

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly
(and btw: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a runnable example where one combo box updates the other

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));

        ComboBox<String> comboBoxOne = new ComboBox<>();
        ComboBox<String> comboBoxTwo = new ComboBox<>();

        comboBoxOne.getItems().addAll(list);
        comboBoxOne.setOnAction(event -> {
            comboBoxTwo.getItems().clear();
            ArrayList<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                listTwo.add(comboBoxOne.getValue());
            comboBoxTwo.getItems().addAll(listTwo);
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox(comboBoxOne, comboBoxTwo);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```